# R.dimen.A returns an unreasonably big number

Tags: android

I have following line in dimens.xml;

```
<dimen name="pagePadding">8dp</dimen>
```

and following line in my activity class;

```
int d = R.dimen.pagePadding;
```

When I put a breakpoint right after this line, I expect d to be a number like 16 or 24 depending on my pixel density but instead it is a huge number, 2131099861 exactly. Why could this be?

Comment: It's only a resource identifier. You have to resolve it using `context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(int)`, as resources may vary depending on configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`R.dimen.pagePadding` is a resource identifier. To get the dimension:

- Call `getResources()` on your `Activity` or other `Context`
- Call `getDimension()` on the `Resources`

So, you wind up with:

```
float d = getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.pagePadding);
```